# VS Code can't open the terminal

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

For some reason vscode stopped opening the integrated terminal and now I get an error every time I try to open the terminal. I have already tried reinstalling Git but nothing so far, any idea, here I leave a picture of the config and the error:

[image]

I even tried to change the bash terminal for powershell but still nothing, have no idea what could be happening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue, i just delete the `settings.json`, apparently the file was corrupt some how, after that vs code was working just fine, the only thing is that i need to configure my workspace again, but not big deal.

Comment: Brill... I tried to run VSCode debug but was getting "visual studio code timeout", so maybe I had the same problem.  But I simply deleted ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json, then my debug terminal came back to work correctly ... (VSCode version 1.39.2 on Centos7)

Comment: I was facing same kind of issue. It may help someone.
In setting.json, commented out "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" worked for me.

//"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"

Comment: Same issue here, but in my case the issue was having "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false.

Changing its value to true solved the problem. Also you might need to reload the window to see the effects. Ctrl+Shift+P and search for 'reload window'

Comment: In my settings.json I removed all the entries with `workbench.*` and restarted and it seemed to fix the issue for me

Comment: for me it was big deal to setup from scratch so I tried to investigate and found out there was nothing wrong with my file - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74040716/1665293

Answer (score 7):

I had same without having anything incorrect in `settings.json`.

I didn't find any terminal-related errors in VSCode output tab but my terminal stopped opening all of a sudden.

What helped me to resolve:

1. renamed global `settings.json` > `1settings.json`
2. quit vscode > open vscode > everything works fine
3. created new `settings.json` and copied ALL content from `1settings.json`
4. quit vscode > open vscode > everything works fine

Not sure what caused this, but my inability to open integrated terminal got fixed by this manipulation. Probably that might be some update issue.

Comment: It fixed it for me except I didn't do the copy stuff part. Just rename, relaunch, exit, rename, relaunch.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was **this line** in `settings.json` on Linux (CentOS 7):

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "konsole",
```

After removing/commenting it, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Code 2 error is usually when the path is not correct or has been changed. check to see where your bash.exe file is located by using external bash and run "where bash.exe" then just check that is the same on vscode.

Or try removing and leaving the following empty:
terminal.inegrated.Cwd

I had this issue a while back and I removed the cwd and left it clear and it worked fine all i needed was to add the path into the Terminal.integrated.shell.windows and nothing else

If it still does not work let me know what version you are using. and what extensions you have sometimes the extension override settings.

Answer (score 0):

I remove `"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",` in settings.json then I can open the terminal. I guess it is relative to https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/releases v11.18.0
MORE: After that I add `"workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",` again and I can open terminal normally. I have no idea =)))

Answer (score 0):

on Mac, stopping all terminals and restarting the device fixed it for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33423652)