# Unable to launch VSCode in WSL

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have wsl (1) installed and set to automatically run with bash. I'm not sure what changed, but suddenly I'm unable to open vscode from the bash terminal. when I run "code" or "code ." I don't get an error or anything, vscode just never opens. I've even tried running "code" from the actual directory where it exists (/c/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code). I'm at a total loss here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code can't open the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54331595/vs-code-cant-open-the-terminal)

Comment: @Skynet no it does not.

Comment: You need VS Code Server installed on your WSL guest, and "Remote - WSL" extension installed in VSCode on WSL host. Both must be properly configured or it won't work.

Comment: I have the same problem. It was working perfectly for months, and today I ran code from WSL and it put out some update messages and then wouldn't launch the GUI. It also prevents me from launching VSCode from Windows. No instances are running anywhere in WSL or Windows. Only a reboot allows me to launch from Windows. WSL launch is dead.